# null values aren't returned unless specified - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql

When attempting to run a select statement that simply excludes some data, null values are wrongfully (?) being excluded as well.

Using table a:

```
ID         NAME
1          Foo
2          Bar
3          (null)
```

The following statement:

```
select * from a where NAME<>'Foo'
```

is returning the following:

```
ID         NAME
2          Bar
```

Why is ID 3 not returned as a result of this statement? To include the record with the null value, I must change my select statement to

```
select * from a where (NAME<>'Foo' or NAME is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how SQL works. `(NULL <> 'Foo')` returns `NULL`, which fails the conditional. If you want to include that row, you either need `OR NAME IS NULL` or you need to consider storing an empty string instead of NULL, if appropriate for your use-case.

http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/sql_server_2/What_Are_NULL_Values.html has more information on NULL values and boolean operators.